# Dart output observatory listening on port 46670

Tags: dart

When i execute a dart command-line application, i have got the following output.

What is this Observatory listening on 127.0.0.1:46670 mean? For what do dart listen on this port?
[image: Port]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what Observatory is?
see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ww8ISWzZGRE for more information.

In Dartium (for browser apps) open the developer tools and switch to the 'Observatory' tab. Here you can analyze a lot of runtime information of your app. I don't know how to connect this to a server app or if this is yet supported but if it is not possible yet this is obviosly planned.